# Does Angular 2.0 have something similar to `$setPristine` function in Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular

After submitting the form, the `pristine` state of the input is still "false". I don't know how to reset the `pristine` state to be true. In Angular 1, I would use the `$setPristine` function.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the API and developer guide. There is no API to reset input to pristine.

Instead [developer guide on forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) (section "Add a hero and reset the form"), shows a mechanism to reset form to pristine by adding a active flag on the component. And then binding it on form tag with ngIf

```
  active = true;

  newHero() {
    this.model = new Hero(42, '', '');
    this.active = false;
    setTimeout(()=> this.active=true, 0);
  }
```

and

`<form *ngIf="active">`

This regenerates the form, setting its controls back to pristine.

Comment: I've tried this method However the whole webpage will refresh after "active" is set to be true again. And the data is gone after the page is refreshed.

Comment: And the developer guide also mention that adding active is just a temporary way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pull request waiting to be added https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6679
See also this related issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933

The usually used workaround is to recreate the form.

Comment: Thanks. So there is still no formal way to reset the attribute such as dirty, touched, etc, I guess.

Comment: No, not before the PR is added.